# 32bit 実行ファイルで cifs マウント先の readdir() が NULLになる

Tags: linux, c, gcc

次のプログラムを x86_64 Linux 環境 (Centos7) でコンパイルし、CIFSでマウントした ディレクトリの中身を 表示させようとしました。

gcc のオプションに `-m32` をつけて 32bit でコンパイルしたときと、64bit でコンパイルした場合で、動作が異なり 32bit だと正しく 表示されません。

なぜ 32bit 版は正常に動作しないのでしょうか。
または、正常に動作させる方法が分かれば教えてください。

**追記**
`errno` の値と、`perror()` でエラーメッセージを表示させるようにサンプルを変更しました。
`errno:12: Cannot allocate memory` と表示されましたが、メモリは 1GB以上空いてるので メモリ不足ということはないと思います。
**追記ここまで**

```
// readdir() sample code
// usage : programname directory
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <dirent.h>
#include        <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        struct  dirent  *entry;
        DIR     *dir;
        int     cnt = 0;
        char    errmsg[16];

        // 引数チェック
        if (argc <= 1) return 2;

        dir = opendir( argv[1] );
        if (dir == NULL) return 1;
        printf( "directory opened\n");

        while( (entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                // ディレクトリ エントリーの名前を表示
                printf("d_name: %s\n", entry->d_name);
                cnt++;
        }
        // errno メッセージを表示
        sprintf(errmsg, "errno:%d", errno);
        perror(errmsg);

        closedir( dir );
        printf( "directory closed\n");

        // ディレクトリエントリの数を表示
        printf( "cnt = %d\n", cnt );
        return 0;
}
```

**コンパイル**

```
$ gcc -m32 -o a.i686 sample.c
$ gcc -o a.x86_64 sample.c
```

**実行結果**

```
$ ./a.x86_64 /mnt/cifs/
directory opened
d_name: .          ←ディレクトリの中身が参照できてる
d_name: ..         ←ディレクトリの中身が参照できてる
d_name: test.txt   ←ディレクトリの中身が参照できてる
errno:0: Success
directory closed
cnt = 3            ←中身は 3件あった
$ ./a.i686 /mnt/cifs/
directory opened
errno:12: Cannot allocate memory    ←メモリが確保できない？
directory closed
cnt = 0            ←中身が 0件となる
```

**クライアント環境**

- Linux datacos7 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
- cifs-utils-6.2-10.el7.x86_64
- gcc-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
- glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.3 (i686とx86_64)

**サーバー環境**

- Windows 2016 Server

Comment: CIFS以外のファイルシステムではどうなりますか？

Comment: xfsでは正常に読み込めました。nfsで試したところ cifsと同様に 中身は0件になりました。

Comment: readdirがNULLを返したときerrnoの値はどうなっているでしょうか？ readdirはディレクトリの末端に到達した場合も、エラーの場合も NULL を返すようです。エラーの場合は errno を設定するとのこと [readdir(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

Comment: ファイルシステムに依存するということはプログラムには問題がなく、CentOS 7.6の問題かもしれませんね。まだリリースしたばかりですし。

Comment: errnoは12、perror()すると`Cannot allocate memory` でした。OSバージョン変えて試してみます。

Comment: Centos6.10 x86_64 で試しましたが同じ現象でした。i686 だと正常に動いたので 64bitのカーネルで、32bit コンパイルしたものが再現するようです。`Cannot allocate memory` についてはFreeメモリが1GB以上あるので メモリ不足ではないと思います。64/32bit の関係で なにかおかしいんでしょうな・・・。

Comment: [readdir(3) fails for cifs mount in 32-bit process on amd64](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/676171) 昔からあるんでしょうか、でも相手にされていませんねぇ…。

Comment: おお、類似の事例が知りたかったので助かります。カーネルのバグのようですね。ニッチな要求なので 放置なのか、分かりませんが 解決方法は無さそうなので 別の回避方法を考えたいと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

自己解決しました。

コンパイル時に `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` をつけて実行すると正常に動きました。

```
$ gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m32  -o a64.i386 sample.c
$ ./a64.i386 /mnt/cifs
sizeof long: 4
directory opened
d_name: .
d_name: ..
d_name: test.txt
errno:0: Success
directory closed
cnt = 3
```

man feature_test_macros より引用

> _FILE_OFFSET_BITS
>   このマクロを値 64 で定義すると、ファイル I/O とファイルシステム操作に 関連する 32 ビット版の関数とデータタイプは自動的に 64 ビット版に 変換される。
>   これは、32 ビットシステムで大きなファイル (> 2 ギガバイト) の I/O を実行する際に役立つ (このマクロを定義すると、コンパイルし直すだけで大きなファイルを 扱えるプログラムを書くことができる)。
>   64 ビットシステムは、もともと 2 ギガバイトより大きなファイルを扱えるので、64 ビットシステムではこのマクロは効果を持たない。

dirent.hを見てみると `readdir64`と言うと、関数がありました。

このマクロを有効化してreaddirを呼び出すとreaddir64が実行されるっぽいです。